# Loading Interop.Word.dll during runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, ms-word, runtime, interop

I am currently working on a small console app that should have some sort of integration with Microsoft Word. I guess users might have different versions of Microsoft Office and thats why I decided to load interop asseblies during runtime (however I'm not sure that is right decision).

The next code throws an exception `System.ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name`. As I understand the problem is `WordInterop.GetType("Application")` returns null, however I do not understand why.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly WordInterop = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Windows\\assembly\\GAC_MSIL\\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll");
        Assembly Office = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\Windows\\assembly\\GAC_MSIL\\office\\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\\OFFICE.DLL");

        Type WordApp = WordInterop.GetType("Application");
        dynamic wordAppInst = Activator.CreateInstance(WordApp);
        wordAppInst.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: If you need just open *.doc || *.docx files from application, you can use:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"PATH_TO_FILE");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I Found out the problem was in type name.
Should be `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass` instead of `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
var wordAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application")
var wordAppInst = Activator.CreateInstance(wordAppType);
```